# Show the title and content for all the Evernote notes with the same title

Tags: python, django, data-structures, evernote

How to Show all the notes with the same title and show their title alongside with content.

Do you know how to display the  title & content  for each note ?
as in https://sandbox.evernote.com.

I have a few notes with the same title and would like to display all the list of such notes alongside with others notes.

```
What the right combination of lists and dicts or other structures ?
```

I got the error: list indices must be integers, not str.

```
nb = []
nb.append([])
for note in result_list.notes:
    content = note_store.getNoteContent(auth_token, 
                                        note_store.getNote(note.guid, 
                                        True,False, False, False).guid)
    nb[note.guid].append([note.title, html2text.html2text(BeautifulSoup(ENMLToHTML(content), "html.parser").prettify()) ])
return render_to_response('oauth/callback.html', {'notebooks': notebooks, 
                                                  'result_list': result_list, 
                                                  'nb': nb})
```

.

```
<ul>
  {% for i,j,n in enumerate(nb) %}
      <li><b>{{ nb[i][j][n] }}</b><br>{{ nb[i][j][n+1] }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

the sample of desirable output:

- **2600 Magazine: The Hacker Quarterly**
  any sort of liquid damage to an Apple product will void your warranty.

I already have the working code that output in such way, but 
currently:

> show only one note per title,
>   or
>   show all the notes with the same title and show the guid alongside with content (good that all the notes, but I need to output the title alongside with content)

p.s

another attempt:

```
title_contents = {}
    for note in result_list.notes:
        content = note_store.getNoteContent(auth_token, 
                                            note_store.getNote(note.guid, 
                                            True,False, False, False).guid)
        title_contents[ note.guid ] = [ note.title, html2text.html2text(BeautifulSoup(ENMLToHTML(content), "html.parser").prettify()) ]
    return render_to_response('oauth/callback.html', {'notebooks': notebooks, 
                                                      'result_list': result_list, 
                                                      'title_contents': title_contents})
```

html for Django:

```
  <ul>
    {% for content in title_contents.items %}
      <li><b>{{ content }}</b><br>{{ content }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

current output:

**('c41c95b1-d2c5-481d-9fa6-34342371aba3', ['hi', u'hello stackoverflow\n\n'])**
('c41c95b1-d2c5-481d-9fa6-34342371aba3', ['hi', u'hello stackoverflow\n\n'])

I tried to get the title and content by index , for example:

```
  <ul>
    {% for content in title_contents.items %}
      <li><b>{{ content[0] }}</b><br>{{ content[1] }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

but get another error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /callback/

Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'content[0]'
```

---

10 feb 2016:

[image: Without any changes (without indent)]

[image: With indent]

I began writing this web app with **Node Js**,
 
and all the things worked correctly in console (but of course with token oauth, only display the text, import the notes from the file(simple parsing), display the chosen note, etc ).

I need the similar app with simple web interface, ideally with Node Js Express.

While struggling with Node Js **Express**, I began writing something similar in Python (Django).
I don't know which one of the frameworks (Express or Django) will be easier to deal with all the challenges. 
And that's why I working on both projects.

EDAMTest.js is very simple and clear, but works only in console environment. 
Node Js Express is much better than Django for me in that case, but I thought that with Django it will be easier to implement.

Comment: Please don't modify your question to add another question.

Comment: okay,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327980/how-to-show-the-title-of-each-evernote-note-in-express-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution !!!

the **dict of tuples**

...

note_store.getNoteContent(auth_token, note.guid)

...

```
<ul>
  {% for m,t in title_contents.items %}
    <li><b>{{ t.0 }}</b><br>{{ t.1 }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you want to group the content of all notes with the same title. The first thing to figure out here is the data structure. A python dict sounds appropriate, since you care about a mapping from note titles. Since note titles can map to multiple notes, the mapping should probably be from a string (the note title) to a list of strings (the note content of all the notes that have that title). For the cases where only one note has that title (probably most cases), the list of note content will be of size 1.

It's been a while since I've written python/django, but to use pieces of your code:

```
title_contents = {}
for note in result_list.notes:
    content = note_store.getNoteContent(auth_token, 
                                        note_store.getNote(note.guid, 
                                        True,False, False, False).guid)
note_content = html2text.html2text(BeautifulSoup(ENMLToHTML(content)).prettify())
existing_contents = title_contents.get(note.guid, [])
existing_contents.append(note_content)
title_contents[note.guid] = existing_contents
```

at the end of this, we have a data structure that looks like this

```
{ 'test title': ['foo contents'], 'untitled': ['one content', 'another content']}
```

Now, in your template, you'll need to loop over all the titles and all the notes in there. You'll probably need to correct my syntax, but it'll look something like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for title, content_list in title_contents %}
      <li><b>{{ title }}</b><br>
      {% for content in content_list %}
        {{ content }}<br/>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks @akhaku, the code looks interesting,
but I get the error:
`'list' object has no attribute 'push'`

Comment: I add 

    `class List(list):`
        `def push(self, x):`
            `self.append(x)`

but I still get that error

Comment: if I use 'append' instead 'push', this part of code don't output anything.

Comment: Sorry, I did a couple things wrong. I meant to use list.append, been doing too much javascript lately. I also meant to put existing_contents back into note_content, see updated answer.

Answer (score -2):

The error implies that `note.guid` is a string, and since you're using it as a list index, it must be an integer instead.

You could use 
`print(repr(note.guid), type(note.guid))` 
so that you can see what it is and adjust accordingly.

If it's a string like: `'3'` then you can just convert it like: `int(note.guid)`

Comment: Thanks but the note.guid contain lowercase characters and '-',
for example:
28aeb0dc-6080-43c2-a527-294e4cb66b51

Comment: Right, so you can't use it as a list index. What do you want `nb` to look like when it completes?

Comment: Perhaps you want it (`nb`) to be a dictionary, not a list, which looks like what you've done in your second attempt. What's the other error for that?

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError at /callback/

Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'content[0]'

Comment: Casting a string to an int for indexing purposes isn't usually a good idea. If you're trying to use a string as an index, you should usually be using a map (a dict, in python).

Comment: I was only suggesting that IF the string looked like an integer. As my comments show, I said the same thing as you about using a dict if it's not an indexed list.